# wxPython - the frame isn't opening as it's programmed

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, python-2.6

When I run the following program, all I get is a little window, and a small text box (text box), according to the program, it should be a big window, bigger text box and two buttons.

```
import wx

class FirstFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'PIZZA', size=(400,400))
        self.sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(2,2,5,5)
        panel=wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.button1 = wx.Button(panel,id=-1,label='Click Me!', size=(20,20))
        self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel,id=-1,size=(50,50))
        self.button2 = wx.Button(panel,-1,'Click Me Too!',size=(20,20))
        #trying to use the boxer...
        self.sizer.Add(self.textbox)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button1)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button2)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

class MyGame(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=FirstFrame(None,-1,"wx")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app=MyGame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer:
Apparently it happens sometimes when the class has the commands to paint the background or set position on the frame, without using a sizer. 
About 10 weeks later, when the whole project was done, it sorted itself out.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to change the last line in your `__init__` to the following:

```
panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
```

Here is the code in context:

```
import wx

class FirstFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'PIZZA', size=(400,400))
        self.sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(2,2,5,5)
        panel=wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.button1 = wx.Button(panel,id=-1,label='Click Me!', size=(20,20))
        self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel,id=-1,size=(50,50))
        self.button2 = wx.Button(panel,-1,'Click Me Too!',size=(20,20))
        #trying to use the boxer...
        self.sizer.Add(self.textbox)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button1)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button2)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

class MyGame(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=FirstFrame(None,-1,"wx")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app=MyGame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Personally, I don't use `Fit()` or `SetSizerAndFit()` because of strange issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sizers you shouldn't use fixed sizes, let the sizers do their job:).

So remove the 'size=' from the buttons and text control and change the last line in your init to 'panel.SetSizer(self.sizer), your sizer controls things which are children of your panel, so don't set it to the frame.  As the panel is the only thing in the frame that works, otherwise you would need another sizer for the frame.

I am a fan of the sized_controls, so here how you would do it using them, they handle all the sizer stuff automagically, but they still give you control if you need to, check out the wxPython demo and/or the doc at: [sized_controls doc](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.sized_controls.html#module-lib.sized_controls)

```
import wx
import wx.lib.sized_controls as sc

class FirstFrame(sc.SizedFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        super(FirstFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, 'PIZZA')
        pane = self.GetContentsPane()
        self.button1 = wx.Button(pane,id=-1,label='Click Me!')
        self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(pane,id=-1)
        self.button2 = wx.Button(pane,-1,'Click Me Too!')

class MyGame(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=FirstFrame(None,-1,"wx")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app=MyGame()
app.MainLoop()
```